# Batch File String Storage And Modification?

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 questions.

***Question 1***: A string containing the following output (from wget) which is already stored in:

```
wgetstring=Length 2012123 (20M) [text.txt something]
                  ↑                                ↑ <-- This data can be random.
```

Now I want to delete all character after the "*Length 2012123*" from that "*wgetstring*", How can I achieve that?

---

***Question 2***: I have a string containing the following output (from cmd) which is already stored in:

```
cmdstring=cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\main.bat" "C:\Users\Ben\script.bat"
                     ↑                              ↑ ↑                       ↑ <-- This data can be random.
```

Now I want to store only this output (*""C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\main.bat"*) from the "*cmdstring*" output so it can be further stored as

```
cmdstringupdated=C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\main.bat
```

but, without any quotes.

---

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is the wget output stored in a file or you want to execute the command directly?

Comment: It is stored in a string through a for loop so, I guess directly? Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1.

Assuming that you'll execute the wget directly

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a  in ('wget command') do (
   set "len_str=%%a %%b"
) 
echo %len_str%
```

Q2 .

```
@echo off
set "some_string=cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\main.bat" "C:\Users\Ben\script.bat""

echo %some_string%
set some_string=%some_string:""="%
for /f "usebackq tokens=3" %%a in ('%some_string%') do echo %%~a

rem :: or use this
call :p %some_string%

exit /b 0

:p

echo %~3
```

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear enough in my previous post (I have updated it now). There seems to be double space after "%%a" and where does that "%%b" comes from? and the second answer you provided seem like quotes """ have been misplaced. Thank you and I appreciate the quick response. Cheers.

Comment: @Anonymous `%%b` is  the second named token in for /f command.THe first is %%a - http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html  .  This usage `set "varaiable=value"` is used to include special symbols in the `value` without escapes. Like quotes.

Comment: @Anonymous - looks like there's one missing quote at the end in your second question.

Comment: I rechecked it with the command itself inside the loop (I was previously checking it with stored string) and it worked (and I learned something very new, thanks to you.). About the second question it not actually missing the quote as the first one has actually double quotes and in the end only one. So its not a typo.

Comment: The second command seems to be not working. The system cannot find the file.."cmd.exe /c "...." and echo's other commands like pause and at the end "ECHO is off" is shown.

Comment: @Anonymous - check my edit.It was because of the quotes.`usebackq` option was added.

Comment: No luck, output is only shown as "%i" and your edit still doesn't have double quotes (cmd.exe /c ""C:\Users..) notice the double quote? (it's not a typo)

Comment: @Anonymous - check my edit.Exactly the non-closed double quotes are the problem.Now they are there and stripped.

Comment: Wow and i thought i know batch files..Thank you very much for your time and effort (I'll surely learn from this). Cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75646/discussion-between-anonymous-and-npocmaka).